# Laravel 9 Eloquent relations with UUID

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-9

why the user_id is set to ? in Eloquent hasOne relation's sql query

```
"select * from `files` where `files`.`user_id` = ? and `files`.`user_id` is not null",
```

here's the model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, SoftDeletes,HasUuids;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        
    ];

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'id'=>'string',
    ];
    public function profile_picture(){
        return $this->hasOne(File::class);
    }

}
```

and the file model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasUuids;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    use HasFactory,HasUuids;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'content',
        'extension',
    ];

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

migrations:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->softDeletes($column = 'deleted_at', $precision = 0);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

```
Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->unique();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('extension');
            $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps(); 
        });
```

Instead of using auto-incrementing integers as your Eloquent model's primary keys, you may choose to use UUIDs instead. UUIDs are universally unique alpha-numeric identifiers that are 36 characters long.

code php explain the problem and the corect code.

Comment: `?` show in prepared statements, laravel uses prepared statements and then binds the correct parameters to the query at the time the query is executed, replacing the question marks.

Comment: But it supose to be auto generated 
$file = $user->profile_picture()->toSql(); this method gives me the query above however if I user Query builder it works just fine like: $file = File::where('user_id', $id)->first();

Comment: Try `$user->profile_picture()->dd()` to also see the bindings that replace the question-mark, toSql will not include these

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: after I try this shown:"select * from `files` where `files`.`user_id` = ? and `files`.`user_id` is not null" // vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:3760                                                 array:1 [ // vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:3760
  0 => "98391fa1-c70a-48c8-a749-3ac66bd3db45"
]

Comment: looks like it will work perfect to me? not sure what your error is, that will compile to `select * from files where files.user_id = '98391fa1-c70a-48c8-a749-3ac66bd3db45' and files.user_id is not null`

Comment: I want to return the profile picture with eloquent relation without query builder. the sql statement that is generated by the relation is as above missing user_id's value so it returns null. I want to fix that.

Comment: To me it seems somthimg wrong I can give you the github url if you have time to take a look: https://github.com/hoceyne/numidia-education-system

Comment: to me it won't compile as exepected.

Comment: It's not missing the user_id, the user_id is `98391fa1-c70a-48c8-a749-3ac66bd3db45` or at least that is the UUID you're giving it

Comment: then why it returns null

Comment: It works I just replace ->profile_picture() with ->profile_picture without the prentecies